# Vlookup Returns Values for some cells but not others

Tags: excel, vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP($I2&"|"&$J$1,MatrixD!A1:D5030,4,0)
```

That's my formula for the problem I am having. So the problem is this will return the proper value for say the first ten values when dragged down then it will show N/A for the remaining values that are exactly a like. The other problem is if I manually go and write the formula in it gets a value. So why does it works for some and not for others when everything is the same and i've checked for spaces and formatting issues everything came back true when tested.

For a little more context it is looking for a value in a helper row (ex.ABC|123)
so the first part of the formula is putting together the value it should look for since there are eight things for each ABC.

Answer (score 1):

Dragging down `MatrixD!A1:D5030` it does not remain "exactly the same" - Excel automatically adjusts the range when not anchored (with `$`s).

Comment: So use this : MatrixD!$A$1:$D$5030

Comment: Thanks I noticed this right after I posted, just needed to turn my brain on lol